# Match all attributes of all tags except the specific tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Good morning, I'm trying to use regular expressions to select all attributes, but I don't want to select the attributes of a specific tag. My code:

```
/("([^"]*)\")/g
```

Example: https://regexr.com/66nup

The code works fine, I just want to exclude the attributes from the "Variable" tag.

Comment: You can match the string starting with `<variable` to prevent capturing the values `<variable[^<>]*>|("([^"]*)")` https://regex101.com/r/aofYjN/1 But note that the pattern that captures the values is not related to tags, it just matches all strings between double quotes.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to replace the double quotes of all attributes with single quotes. The only double quotes I want to keep are the ones for the "variable" tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
/<variable.*?>/g
```

That removes just the `<variable includable id='image'>` from your linked example.
Or do you also need it to remove the `</b:includable>` right after?